# React-Node File Uploader

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

So I am having a really really hard time getting file uploading to work.  I didn't think this was going to be as challenging as it has been.

So I'll start with the simple HTML element:

```
<input type="file" id="server-avatar-file" className="file-input" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onChange={this.handleChange} style={{position: "absolute", top: "0px", left: "0px", width: "100%", height: "100%", opacity: "0", cursor: "pointer"}} />
```

Here is my submit of the form data:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        axios.post('/api/v1/testing/upload',
            this.state.file)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

I've used busboy, multipart everything I can think of.

I however believe the issue is stemming from my front-end not sending all the correct info to my backend.

That is what this.state.file has as it's value:

[image]

I understand bodyParser in Node does not parse file types, and I am unfamiliar with how to parse them on the server.  I would like to test it by uploading to my file system, but would like to move over to a CDN in production, so something that makes it easy for me to do that would be great!

Comment: Have you tried using a `FormData` instance instead of a raw `File` object? With that `busboy`, `multer`, etc. should work fine.

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb, that's all it was, you'd think I would've ran into needing to do that after all the googling I did.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`busboy`, `multer`, and other multipart parsing modules require properly formatted multipart/form-data requests. One easy way to send a request like this with axios is to instead pass a `FormData` instance instead of a raw `File` or `Blob` instance as the data argument.